# DevExpress XPO XPCollection Refreshing Changes

Tags: session, devexpress, xtragrid, xpo

I'm experiencing an issue refreshing data in XPCollection after commiting some database changes using UnitOfWork.

I have a WinForm with an XPCollection.

The XPCollection uses XpoDefault.Session.

I do some changes through a UnitOfWork:

```
using (UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork())
    {
    var photos = new XPCollection<Photo>(uow);
    photos[0].Date = DateTime.Now;
    uow.CommitTransaction();

    }
```

To get the original XPCollection to update the changes, I've tried the following:

```
foreach (Photo photo in myXPCollection)
{
XpoDefault.Session.Reload(photo);
}

foreach (Photo photo in myXPCollection)
{
photo.Reload();           
}

myXPCollection.Reload()
```

None of the methods work.The changes are not reflected in the original XPCollection.

They are only visible when I start with a completely new Session. Obviously, this is a big performance problem.

How to get the changes made using UnitOfWork to another Session?

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> They are only visible when I start with a completely new Session. Obviously, this is a big performance problem.

That's exactly what you should do. Create a new `UnitOfWork` each time you want refreshed data. A `UnitOfWork` is very cheap performance-wise to instantiate. If you have a large collection of `Photo` objects, you should improve performance by loading only the objects you need by specifying the `Criteria` parameter in the `XPCollection<Photo>` constructor.

When you issue `Reload()` it doesn't fetch anything from the database: it discards any changes and reloads the object from the session identity map. You can read [this article](http://www.devexpress.com/products/net/orm_old/articles/sessionmanagementcaching.xml) and [this Support Center issue](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/A643.aspx) for more information.

By the way, the [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center) is by far the best place to ask DevExpress questions.

Comment: Creating a new Session every time looks illogical to me. Isn't there a way to just force the existing XPCollection/Session to refresh from the data source?

Comment: You shouldn't need to refresh from the data source. Oh I see, you're using the wrong commit. Change it to `uow.CommitChanges()`.

Comment: `CommitTransaction()` is for [transactions](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XPO/CustomDocument2111).

Comment: Good find. But the changes are still not available with the original Session, even after CommitChanges in UnitOfWork.

Comment: You're doing something wrong. Here's [a working sample program](https://gist.github.com/shamp00/5347869).